# Using Colored Underlines in Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, errors, color, underline

I am trying to underline specific terms in math mode in color. Right now, I have defined a command:

`\newcommand{\ula}[1]{{\setulcolor{red}\ul{#1}}}`

While this command works on normal text, it doesn't work at all in math mode. For instance, if I tried to do this:

`$\ula{a + b} = c$`

The result is a red underline without the a + b, and the only text that appears is "= c". Some help on this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, possibly starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: So you want the `a + b` to be underlined in red in math mode too?